# How to use response object from Spring controller in Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am trying to display the objects' data passed as an ArrayList response. I am able to see the content of the objects but unable to use it in the angularjs view.
Here is my Spring controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList<ConceptModelDetails> getAllTasks() {
            ArrayList<ConceptModelDetails> list = new ArrayList<ConceptModelDetails>();
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                            "Spring-module.xml");
            JDBCConceptModelDAO objDAO = (JDBCConceptModelDAO) context
                            .getBean("objDAO");
            list = objDAO.getData();
            return list;
    }
```

Here is the view page2

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.mi n.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="page2" method="post">
            <h1>
                    Success: <input type="submit" value="See Data">
            </h1>
    </form>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">

            <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in object">
                            <td>${ x.requestor }</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
    </div>

    <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {
                                            $http.post("page2")
                                                            .success(function(response) {
                                                                    $scope.object = response.records;                                                                        
                                                            console.log(response);
                                                            });                        

            });
    </script>
```

After clicking on see Data, I am getting the following output:

[image: Output]

But I want to display the data in a table.

Comment: You could use external modules like UI-Grid https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid

Comment: I think you should take a look at https://spring.io/blog/2015/08/19/migrating-a-spring-web-mvc-application-from-jsp-to-angularjs, currently you are doing something definitely wrong with the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The `response` object is just a JavaScript array of objects. You can then bind it to an [ngGrid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/) component to render it.

In html:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
    </div>
</body>
```

In JavaScript:

```
$scope.conceptModelDetailsList = response;
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'conceptModelDetailsList' };
```

Note that this is just one way to do it. There are many different way to render the list like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a fundamental mistake here.

Please understand the Spring MVC concept well. These tutorials will help you in understanding this.

- [Spring - MVC Framework Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm)
- [Mkyong - Spring MVC Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/)
- [Spring MVC Official doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

In the above code `public @ResponseBody ArrayList<ConceptModelDetails> getAllTasks(){...}` the method returns `ArrayList<ConceptModelDetails>`. This is converted into `JSON` due to the presence of `@ResponseBody`.

Now you have to consume it in AngularJS grid-ui using the AJAX call.
Explaining you the same here is out of scope, please learn angular from the 
 [W3School AngularJS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/)

Once you are familiar with `Spring MVC` and `REST API` concepts in Spring, look into [Angular UI Grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid) to display the JSON data.

If you just want to display the `ArrayList` in a view, please learn about the `Model` and how to iterate it in `JSTL`. This is explained in the above spring tutorials.

This is a long process, there is no shortcut to become a developer!

Hope it helps!